Sur la source de la décision de l’Académie concernant l'emploi du participe présent en 1679
Bonjour,
Comme on le sait, le participe présent en français est devenu invariable suite à la décision de l'Académie en 1679.
À ce sujet, par exemple, la Grammaire des Grammaires de Charles-Pierre Girault-Duvivier (p. 704), également citée dans Littré s. v. décliner sous la rubrique supplément au dictionnaire, indique :
L’Académie prononça le 3 juin 1679 : « La règle est faite, on ne déclinera plus les participes présents. »
(URL : https://books.google.ca/books?id=LIwGAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Grammaire+des+grammaires&source=bl&ots=I67eqpOKaH&sig=Rp7AJhmGXVVG1RIONJN7nJ8XTIc&hl=fr&ei=lixATeLEO4HagAeCq-WFAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=regle%20est%20faite&f=false)
Cependant, j'ai recherché la source originale de cette décision de l'Académie sur Internet, mais je n'ai pas réussi à la trouver.
J'aimerais consulter le document original de cette décision de 1679.
Quelqu'un saurait-il où je pourrais le trouver ?
Je vous remercie par avance.

Peut-être ici : https://www.academie-francaise.fr/

Merci de votre réponse. Il s'agit d'un site officiel mais il me semble que la décision de 1679 ne s'y trouve pas.

L'endroit le plus probable pour trouver les archives des publications (dans le cas présent je pense qu'il s'agit d'une ordonnance) de l'Académie Française est la BNF.

Je doute fort que l'on puisse attribuer à l'Académie en 1679 les mots exacts de la citation telle qu'on la trouve dans le Littré ou dans la Grammaire des Grammaires de  Girault-Duvivier, publications du (XIXe siècle) car le terme de « participe présent » n'a commencé à être employé qu'après le XVIIe siècle et en 1679 l'Académie Française parlait encore de « participe actif » (et de « participe passif » pour ce qu'on nomme de nos jours le « participe passé »).  Voir l'article Participe de la 1re édition du Dictionnaire de l'Académie française (1694) :

Terme de Grammaire. Partie d’oraison. C’est parmi nous un adjectif qui est formé d’un verbe, & qui retient le regime du verbe dont il est formé : & il y en a de deux sortes ; l’un actif qui est indeclinable, & l’autre passif, qui se decline comme les autres noms adjectifs.

Ce n'est que dans la 6e édition du Dictionnaire (1835) que les termes de « présent » et « passé » sont introduits pour la première fois en association avec la notion de participe.
En plus de l'article « participe » figurant dans la première édition du Grand Dictionnaire de l'Académie françoise on trouve tout un paragraphe mentionnant l'invariabilité du « participe actif » dans la préface de l'édition publié l'année suivante, en 1695 :

Le texte que Girault-Duvivier (première édition de sa Grammaire des grammaires, 1811) a  très probablement consulté sont les Registres de l'Académie, qui retranscrivent les séances de l'Académie. Un extrait de celle  du 3 juin 1679 intitulé Des participes actifs, est reproduite dans les Opuscules sur la langue françoise que l'on peut consulter sur Gallica et dont voici la fin du dernier paragraphe :

C'est à partir de la conclusion de la discussion, dernière phrase du paragraphe : « Ainsi la règle est faite, qu'on ne déclinera point les participes actifs. » que Girault-Duvivier a ensuite rédigé une phrase compréhensible pour les lecteurs du XIXe siècle.

J'apprécie beaucoup votre remarque très détaillée et précise.
Le texte que je cherchais se trouve exactement dans le Registre de l'Académie de 1679, que vous avez trouvé !
En outre, je ne le savais pas jusqu'à ce que vous m'ayez fait remarquer que l'expression « participe actif » était plus courante à une certaine époque que  « participe présent ».
Merci pour votre précieuse aide.

Le participe présent n'est pas devenu invariable suite à une décision de l'Académie française. Disons plutôt que les grammairiens du XVIIe siècle, en premier lieu Vaugelas, ont observé qu'il existait des mots en -ant invariables au moins en genre, les participes actifs, mais que lorsque ces mêmes mot étaient employés comme adjectifs, ils prenaient naturellement les marques du féminin et du pluriel.

On respond que tout participe actif & passif doit estre consideré en deux façons, ou comme participe & adjectif tout ensemble, ou comme adjectif seulement. Or il n'est jamais participe au féminin au moins dans le bel usage mais seulement adjectif, quoy que l'on confesse qu'il vient du participe; Car s'il estoit participe au feminin, il regiroit sans doute le mesme cas que regit le verbe dont il est participe, comme il fait au masculin par exemple on dit fort bien je les ay trouvez mangeans des confitures, buvants de la limonade, mais on ne dira jamais en parlant de femmes je les ay trouvées mengeantes des confitures, ny beuvantes de la limonade, ni ayantes le verre à la main, comme nous l'avons dit.
Vaugelas, Remarques sur la langue françoise, utiles à ceux qui veulent bien parler et bien escrire, 1647

L'Académie française n'a donc rien décidé mais a entériné cette observation comme le montre la préface de la première édition Dictionnaire de l'Académie (1694).

Les Participes passifs ont les deux genres & se declinent comme les autres Noms1 aimé, aimée. Les Personnes aimées. Il n’en est pas de mesme des Participes actifs qui n’ont point de genre & qui sont indeclinables. On appelle Participes actifs ceux qui se terminent en ant, comme changeant, donnant, faisant; Et parce que ces Participes ont tousjours le mesme regime & le mesme sens que leurs Verbes, on a creu qu’il n’estoit pas besoin d’en faire mention. Ces mesmes Participes actifs tiennent aussi lieu de Gerondifs quand ils sont construits avec la particule en, En changeant souvent on devient inconstant; En donnant on se fait honneur. Ils font aussi la mesme fonction sans cette particule, il luy dit changeant de discours. Enfin ces Participes deviennent aussi Adjectifs Verbaux, & alors ils ont les deux genres & se construisent selon le genre & le nombre du Substantif auquel ils sont joints; II y a des esprits changeants, des couleurs changeantes; Et quand ces sortes de mots se trouvent dans le Dictionnaire avec les deux genres, ils y sont mis non pas comme Participes actifs, mais comme Adjectifs verbaux. Ainsi le mot changeant n’est point dans le Dictionnaire comme Participe actif, mais comme Adjectif verbal, changeant, changeante; & cela suffit pour faire entendre la nature de ces mots, & quelle a esté la conduite de l’Academie à cet esgard.

1 Nom n'a pas ici le même sens qu'aujourd'hui. A l'époque, nom regroupait d'une part ce qu'on appelait les noms substantifs (les noms communs) et d'autre part les noms adjectifs (aujourd'hui les adjectifs).

Je vous suis profondément reconnaissant pour votre remarque très intéressant ! Grâce à votre réponse, j'ai mieux compris la situation avant et après la décision de 1679. L'expression « noms adjectifs », j'en entends parler pour la premiere fois !
